# What is the trick of "terminal output refresh" (as oppose to plainly output)?

Tags: c++, shell, terminal, clang, bazel

Forgive my description in the title. Here is more exact description :

When I use bazel and clang to compile large number of targets, the command line output will not keep scrolling, instead it fresh when compiling new target. So that we do not have to scroll to see the result.

Anyone one know what kind of trick is that, which tool in this pipe line used it?

I am wondering whether if this trick can be used from native code in C++, such as `std::cout` + special character that terminal would refresh ? 
My use case is that my native c++ code is doing thousands of cycles, my regular output would flush the screen. (Using debugger is not an option for special reasons, so that I have to reply on print statement)

Comment: https://gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

Comment: for simple single line output you can just use a carriage return (`\r`), for more complex cases you need to use the api of your terminal

Comment: You really need a library for this.  C++ doesn't have a concept of a screen or know how to clear/refresh it. That's an OS operation and you need to work with the OS to have it happen so having a library that does this for different OSes is really nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast responses. I will look into all the options provided here!

Answer (score 2):

Bazel implements this with cursor controls, and can be triggered by the [`--curses`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--curses) flag. [Trace the code that adds/clears Bazel progress bars here](https://source.bazel.build/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/runtime/UiEventHandler.java;l=1084-1112;drc=3c13e54a14c7339994bbc97bf1dccce213c7fc44).

> This option determines whether Bazel will use cursor controls in its screen output. This results in less scrolling data, and a more compact, easy-to-read stream of output from Bazel. This works well with `--color`.
>
> If this option is set to yes, use of cursor controls is enabled. If this option is set to no, use of cursor controls is disabled. If this option is set to auto, use of cursor controls will be enabled under the same conditions as for `--color=auto`.

Comment: The option's misnamed (the [referenced code](https://source.bazel.build/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/runtime/UiEventHandler.java;drc=27545a72c45e33cc21535eb0fd05dd01b1e323af;l=268) uses the name, but no curses library).